# Error en $request->get() de laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Espero no molestarlos con este error pero no se como solucionarlo.

Tengo una aplicación, que es para listar carros, en mi laptop funciona correctamente pero ahora que la subo al servidor la función guardar en la base de datos no funciona. Les muestro el código ya que utilizo `$request->get('nombre');` pero cuando lo guardo en la base de datos esta en blanco es decir `$request->get('nombre');` no tiene nada, pero en la laptop funciona bien y si guarda correctamente.

Ademas de eso si edito o elimino usando esto `$request->get('nombre');` si lo hace perfectamente solo guardar no funciona

**Formulario en Laravel**

```
<form method="POST" action="/marcas/nuevo/" class="form-horizontal">
                                    @csrf
                                    <div class="form-row">
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <div class="position-relative form-group"><label for="exampleEmail11" class=""></label><input name="nombre" id="exampleEmail11" placeholder="Digite la  nueva Marca" type="text" class="form-control"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>


                                    <button class="mt-2 btn btn-primary">Crear Marca</button>
                                </form>
```

**WEB RUTAS**

```
Route::post('/marcas/nuevo/', 'Marcas_de_AutosController@nuevo');
```

**Controlador**

```
$tipo_de_autos = new Marcas_de_Autos;

    $tipo_de_autos->marca_auto = $request->get('nombre');
    $tipo_de_autos->save();



    return redirect('/marcas/')->with('success','Guardado Satisfactoriamente !');
```

Answer (score 0):

Estas mandando datos para su inserción en tu BD por medio de `post` en tu formulario y así también en la ruta definida, sin embargo los solicitas por `get` en tu controller.

Considero deberías cambiarlo a simplemente esto:

```
$tipo_de_autos->marca_auto = $request->input('nombre');
```

O bien leyendo la propiedad de este modo:

```
$tipo_de_autos->marca_auto = $request->nombre;
```

Es decir quitas el método `get` puesto que no es por ese método que envías la *data* y en su lugar puedes leer la propiedad directo por el nombre que tiene el `input` o bien por el método `input`

**Referencias**

- [HTTP Requests](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests#accessing-the-request)